jhipster angular compiled successfully, but AggregateError
PREVIOUS ANSWERS DONT WORK SO ITS NOT ALREADY ANSWERED, there are SO answers suggesting to use earlier downgrade node. jhipster8 build successful, then AggregateError which says,

As mentioned in a recent GitHub issue, the current workaround for this
problem is to downgrade the Node version to 18.18.2.

wont work since there is minimum node version required for jhipster 8.7.3 and thats higher then 18.18.2. And using higher version node would still resulted in aggregateError (I tried 4 versions of node already). So what is that issue anyway? What it means aggregateError and how to resolve it? Here is the output:
> npm start

> j-0@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start
> ng serve --hmr

NOTICE: Hot Module Replacement (HMR) is enabled for the dev server.
See https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement for information on working with HMR for Webpack.
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.

Initial chunk files                                                                             | Names                                   |  Raw size
vendor.js                                                                                       | vendor                                  |   2.35 MB | 
styles.css, styles.js                                                                           | styles                                  | 524.38 kB | 
polyfills.js                                                                                    | polyfills                               | 352.13 kB | 
runtime.js                                                                                      | runtime                                 |  52.26 kB | 
main.js                                                                                         | main                                    |   1.53 kB | 

                                                                                                | Initial total                           |   3.28 MB

Lazy chunk files                                                                                | Names                                   |  Raw size
src_main_webapp_bootstrap_ts.js                                                                 | bootstrap                               |   3.63 MB | 
src_main_webapp_app_account_account_route_ts.js                                                 | account-account-route                   | 186.32 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_admin_metrics_metrics_component_ts.js                                       | metrics-metrics-component               | 181.89 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_layouts_navbar_navbar_component_ts.js                                       | layouts-navbar-navbar-component         | 167.16 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_admin_user-management_list_user-management_component_ts.js                  | list-user-management-component          |  55.04 kB | 
default-src_main_webapp_app_admin_user-management_update_user-management-update_component_ts.js | update-user-management-update-component |  41.05 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_entities_admin_authority_list_authority_component_ts.js                     | list-authority-component                |  33.76 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_admin_health_health_component_ts.js                                         | health-health-component                 |  29.70 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_admin_configuration_configuration_component_ts.js                           | configuration-configuration-component   |  24.29 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_admin_logs_logs_component_ts.js                                             | logs-logs-component                     |  23.61 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_home_home_component_ts.js                                                   | home-home-component                     |  19.79 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_admin_user-management_detail_user-management-detail_component_ts.js         | detail-user-management-detail-component |  18.91 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_entities_admin_authority_update_authority-update_component_ts.js            | update-authority-update-component       |  18.12 kB | 
common.js                                                                                       | common                                  |  18.09 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_login_login_component_ts.js                                                 | login-login-component                   |  16.15 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_entities_admin_authority_authority_routes_ts.js                             | admin-authority-authority-routes        |   8.72 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_entities_admin_authority_detail_authority-detail_component_ts.js            | detail-authority-detail-component       |   8.66 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_admin_user-management_user-management_route_ts.js                           | user-management-user-management-route   |   5.97 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_admin_admin_routes_ts.js                                                    | admin-admin-routes                      |   2.76 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_admin_docs_docs_component_ts.js                                             | docs-docs-component                     |   2.37 kB | 
src_main_webapp_app_entities_entity_routes_ts.js                                                | entities-entity-routes                  |   1.24 kB | 

Build at: 2024-12-13T10:00:38.781Z - Hash: 483ed856f6b48d5f - Time: 28869ms

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


√ Compiled successfully.
AggregateError


not an answer but "AggregateError" should be an object with an array of errors.  So there's multiple errors happening. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AggregateError

It indicates that multiple errors occurred during the build process. You should review the build logs generated during the compilation process or in the browser's developer console look for the AggregateError to see and analyse the individual errors.
